# attempting to run GUI application, but the GUI never appears

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In trying to run my basic GUI application from Main I have somehow managed to first make the GUI show up (but it was smaller than what I set the size to within the code and not showing any components) then magically (after adding pack() and setlocationrelativeto(null)) it does not pop up at all.  I am using Netbeans (if that helps), in Main it gives me a tooltip that my GUI is "never used" so it runs and outputs "Finished building" rather than continuing to run and showing the GUI.  I have provided 2 sets of code (1) main method and (2) GUI class. Please let me know if I'm being confusing as of course it makes sense in my head but may be communicated badly. I have not included the complete code but if it is necessary please let me know and I will do so.

```
package logTime;

public class LogInTime {   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        LogAppFrame app = new LogAppFrame();  //IDE gives tooltip that app is unused
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("\n\nError Occurred: "); //am going to print message later
    }
  }
}
```

The actual GUI code - does not include imports or actionlisteners:

```
    public void LogAppFrame(){

    frame = new JFrame("Time Log Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cl = new CardLayout();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(cl);
    //frame.setLayout(cl);  
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(375,385));

    logNewFrame = new JPanel();
    logNewFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
    logNewFrame.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    frame.getContentPane().add(logNewFrame, "logNewFrame");

    historyFrame = new JPanel(); 
    historyFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1)); //given 0 for rows to add numerous rows
    historyFrame.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    frame.getContentPane().add(historyFrame, "historyFrame");
    .
    .
    .
    //added lots of components but will not include code as there is no error within this portion of code - i used to have both Main and LogAppFrame class all together and my GUI worked and showed components but I felt it may be best practice not to do it this way and cardlayout wasnt working
    .
    .
    .
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Adding SSCE below:

```
package logTime;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class LogAppFrame{

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static CardLayout cl;
//menu option components
    /**
     * Help option: How To Use/Read Me - explains how to use it 8 Hour Day -
     * shows the arrival and leave time based on lunch type
     */
    /**
     * Log New Date option: shows screen to input new values into date
     */
    /**
     * View Past Dates option: shows all past dates since forever - may add
     * month tabs later
     */
    /**
     * Edit Past Date option: doesnt exist yet but will be added to View Past
     * menu option as side button to edit any old date
     */
    private static JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private static JMenu help;
    private static JMenuItem logNewDate;
    private static JMenuItem viewPastDates;
    private static JMenuItem workDay;
    private static JMenuItem about;
//Log New Date components
    /**
     * 4 labels, 1 button, 1 calendar, 2 dropdowns, 2 textfields, 5x2 gridlayout
     */
    private static JLabel dateToday;
    private static JLabel timeInToday;
    private static JLabel timeOutToday;
    private static JLabel lunchTypeToday;
    private static JLabel timeColon1;
    private static JLabel timeColon2;
    private static JButton saveButton;
    private static JComboBox month;
    private static JComboBox day;
    private static JComboBox year;
    private static JComboBox amPm1;
    private static JComboBox amPm2;
    private static JComboBox hrTimeIn;
    private static JComboBox hrTimeOut;
    private static JComboBox minTimeIn;
    private static JComboBox minTimeOut;
    private static JPanel dateTodayPanel;
    private static JPanel timeInPanel;
    private static JPanel timeOutPanel;
    private static JPanel lunchTypePanel;
    private static JPanel saveButtonPanel;
    private static JComboBox lunchType;
//View Past Dates components
    /**
     * 4x*infinitiy* gridlayout or have a flowlayout, 4 labels
     */
    private static JLabel pastDates;
    private static JLabel pastTimeIns;
    private static JLabel pastTimeOuts;
    private static JLabel pastLunchTypes;
    private static JPanel headers; //holds header labels
    private static JPanel oldLogs; //will hold all past log panels

//Frames to hold the logNew and viewOld views    
    private static JPanel logNewFrame;    
    private static JPanel historyFrame;

    public void LogAppFrame(){

        frame = new JFrame("Time Log Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cl = new CardLayout();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(cl);
        //frame.setLayout(cl);  
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(375,385));

        logNewFrame = new JPanel();
        logNewFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
        logNewFrame.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        frame.getContentPane().add(logNewFrame, "logNewFrame");

        historyFrame = new JPanel(); 
        historyFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1)); //given 0 for rows to add numerous rows
        historyFrame.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        frame.getContentPane().add(historyFrame, "historyFrame");


//Menu components
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        logNewDate = new JMenuItem("Log New Date");
        viewPastDates = new JMenuItem("View Past Dates");

        workDay = new JMenuItem("8 Hour Day");
        about = new JMenuItem("How To ...");
        help.add(workDay);
        help.add(about);

        menuBar.add(logNewDate);
        menuBar.add(viewPastDates);
        menuBar.add(help);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);


        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted doesn't help because we can't execute it to see what the problem might be. So, create a simple example with one component displayed on the frame. Once you get that to work you add 2 components. Once you understand the basics you then move on to a more complex GUI.

Comment: "then magically (after adding pack() and setlocationrelativeto(null)) it does not pop up at all", then why did you add pack() and setLocationRelativeTo(null)? What happens if you remove those and keep the rest?

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not but I see that you are using `getContentPane` a lot but you should call `setContentPane` before that.

Comment: when I removed them, my GUI still does not pop up which makes no sense. I have also tried placing setVisible(true) very near the beginning of my code, say right after adding a component to the frame and still nothing.  What is SSCCE?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Please let me know where you got the info on `setContentPane`. This is not a recommendation that I would make as the contentPane is already set by default and may be used as a BorderLayout-using container. To the OP, please click on this link: [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, I have noticed that the WindowBuilder in Eclipse does that on a new JFrame so I assumed it had to be like that. Did not know that it actually was set by default.

Comment: @nugs Check http://sscce.org/ It's short for Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: you *can* set it if you want to, especially if you're having it paint a size-varying background image, but if not, then getting it as the original poster shows, is perfectly fine. I suspect that his problem lies in code he's not showing us.

Comment: ok I have added SSCE and will also try to this myself to see if it helps at all.

Comment: curiously, when i extend JFrame and use app.setVisible(true) in Main...I get a small popup but I have read that it is bad practice to extend JFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written `void` before the thing that ought to be a constructor. So it is mistaken as a method by the compiler which never gets called. Unfortunately the compiler generates a no-op constructor for you in such a case. Just remove the `void` keyword.

And by the way, remove all the nasty `static` keywords from the fields. That hurts.

Comment: 1+  I call what he's done, creating a *pseudo*-constructor. Another 1+ for the static recommendation.

Comment: sweet jeebus! THANK YOU! and yes I removed the void and static keywords. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write simple gui applications you should check [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). It's drag and drop gui for java that actually works.